# Vim what is the use of exclamation mark in substitute command

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I recently found a substitute command for vim where the author had the `/` replaced by a `!` like this: `:%s!foo!bar` and I don't understand the difference with the traditionnal `:%s/foo/bar`.

I searched some documentation on this syntax but I didn't find anything relevant, so I tried to experiment by myself and I couldn't figure out clearly the difference between the two forms. Here is what I found:

- You can't mix `/` and `!` in the same command. E.g: `:%s/foo!bar` will fail.
- The sign `!` can be useful with patterns including a `/`. For example if I want to replace `</` with `%` in my file I can do `:%s!</!%!g` instead of `:%s/<\//%/g`: I don't need to escape `/` in the first command, but I'd be surprised if that was the only use of `!`.
- Some regex seems to fail with `/` and work propertly with `!` but as I'm far from being a regex master I'm not sure about this point.

So my question is: what is the difference between `/` and `!` in vim substitution and when should I use one instead of the other?

Comment: This question was [also posted at vi.stackexchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3156/51).

Comment: Indeed I made a double post by mistake I flagged it on vim to know what I should do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both can be used as long they are consistent (not mixed). Usually `/` is used. But other char can be used if the string you want to replace contains multiple `/`. For example :

```
:%s!/usr/local/bin!/usr/bin!
:%s:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:
:%s,/usr/local/bin,/usr/bin,
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer! Where can I found a list of the char which can be used as separator? Or the ones which can not be used?

Comment: @statox, it is documented in `:help E146` ( from `:help change.txt` ) .